# Help With Code: Picklist field

Tags: apex, trigger, community, picklist

The Country__c field in my second FOR loop is a picklist field.  How can I change my code to work with picklist?  Thanks in advance.

```
trigger oppMarketAssignment on Opportunity(before insert, before update){ 

    Map<String, Country_Market_Map__c> mMap = New Map<String, Country_Market_Map__c>();

    For(Country_Market_Map__c m: [SELECT Id, Country_Name__c, Market__c, Top_5_Country__c, Top_10_Country__c, Top_20_Country__c FROM Country_Market_Map__c]){
        mMap.put(m.Country_Name__c.toUpperCase(),m);
    }


    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
        if(opp.country__c <> ''){
            if(mMap.containsKey(opp.country__c)){
                 opp.Market_2__c = mMap.get(opp.country__c.toUpperCase()).Market__c; 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing?

Comment: @Lacey, I'm not seeing the market populating into the Market_2__c field. I'm assuming because country__c is a picklist field.  I've the same trigger in the Account object and it works just fine.

Comment: That shouldn't have any impact on the code at all, if it's a standard picklist (not multi) you should be able to treat it like a text field. I assume you've checked that the country in question is in the Country_Market_Map__c table?

Comment: @LaceySnr, after ready your comment. I want back and found the problem.  I was pointing to the wrong market field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `toUpperCase` when you check `containsKey`. I would also recommend checking `String.isNotBlank(opp.Country__c)` instead of checking against empty string. That way you guard against `null` as well.